# Is it possible to disable [Pipeline] messages in Jenkins pipeline console output?

Tags: logging, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on some particular Jenkins pipeline which has many steps included - most of which are written in Groovy - because of that I am seeing many `[Pipeline]` messages which are totally unimportant and unnecessary for me. Is it possible to suppress those?

I am asking for something similiar as in related question 2. but I would like to supress all `[Pipeline]` messages - which includes messages like:

```
[Pipeline] node
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] bat
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

And more...

Related questions:

1. [How to disable command output in jenkins pipeline build logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891926/how-to-disable-command-output-in-jenkins-pipeline-build-logs)
2. [How to suppress source script lines echo in jenkins pipeline console output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947567/how-to-suppress-source-script-lines-echo-in-jenkins-pipeline-console-output)

Comment: Have you find any solution??? I hate those logs entries!

Comment: yes the pipeline logs are still utterly ugly and polluted by irrelevant output!

Comment: Well, atleast for now it seems like the only way is to modify CSS using answer by jimtut. Edit to clarify - This can be done by either using additional plugin or with browser extension like it was stated in comments under his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just fixed this following the CSS-based solution in [Suppress Scripted Pipelines Output in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51110083/suppress-scripted-pipelines-output-in-jenkins)

It looks like the CSS elements might have changed, since the accepted answer:

```
.pipeline-annotated {
    display: none;
}
```

didn't work for me, I had to use the `.pipeline-new-node` CSS class shown in another answer.

Comment: Seems like an answer I have been looking for, but before marking it as a solution I've got to test it :)

Comment: sadly I have still not been able to test this solution. Just by looking at it and the CSS generated within job - it should work fine. Not marking this as an answer tho until I have checked it - I should be able to do this soon.

Comment: thanks for the tip ! unlike other SO answers suggesting to modify Jenkins' CSS with some plugin, I went for the browser extension Stylish (on Chromium) and put the CSS there. That way I can easily toggle it from my browser in case I need to see the full logs.

Answer (score 1):

I've also been looking for a way to reduce the amount of output in my pipeline logs.  Until now, the only results I have found focus on putting `set +x` as the first line of a `sh` step, but that doesn't really do anything for the pipeline step echoes.  I would really love to see a solution that did not rely on editing CSS, but rather on the pipeline code; maybe in the `options` declarative...

Answer (score 0):

One more way by which you can hide script section messages, by placing "@" (without quotes) before any script line that you do not want to print in pipeline

Comment: Is there a reference for this

Answer (score -2):

This is a bit old but have a look at the blue ocean plugin. It totally alters the way you view pipelines and you may find that these messages are no longer an issue.

Comment: Sadly Blue Ocean doesn't allow for certain operations yet, and "visual layer" is not enough to use it. Rather than that I would want to be able to disable or limit this verbose output.