# Disable displaying '[Pipeline]*' lines in Jenkins pipeline logs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Jenkins scripted pipeline logs are littered with lines that begin with `[Pipeline]` that give insight to pipeline flow.  Is there a way, using groovy scripted pipelines, to not include them in the logs?

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/jobs/pipe/jobs/pd.oh52a1/branches/dev/workspace
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo /var/jenkins_home/jobs/pipe/jobs/pd.oh52a1/branches/dev/workspace
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] echo
```

I am hoping I can programmatically enable/disable these at the beginning of a run so I can see them if I want to but turn them off by default.

Comment: My answer is to point you to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134277/is-it-possible-to-disable-pipeline-messages-in-jenkins-pipeline-console-output