# How do I turn off command echo in Jenkins pipeline groovy scripts

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to turn off command echos in Jenkins Pipeline groovy scripts?  The only answers seem to be adding the set +/- for shell commands.  I want to do this for all pipeline dsl commands.

I would like to suppress lines like the following, as they clutter up the output log:

```
    [Pipeline] ansiColor
    [Pipeline] {
    [Pipeline] timestamps
    [Pipeline] {
    [Pipeline] node
    [Pipeline] {
    [Pipeline] stage
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Echo off in Jenkins Console Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797219/echo-off-in-jenkins-console-output)

Comment: I looked and it appears it is only for shell commands.  I want to turn this off for commands I posted above -- Pipeline DSL commands, such as node, stage, etc.

Comment: even if you will find a way to turn it off (I personally did not) I will strongly argue that you need that, cause in cases of failures there are plenty of cases where you need to know which stage was causing failure

Comment: I would typically have my own (cleaner) output for stage demarcations, and similar output.

Comment: These seem to be asking the same, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947567/how-to-suppress-source-script-lines-echo-in-jenkins-pipeline-console-output, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134277/is-it-possible-to-disable-pipeline-messages-in-jenkins-pipeline-console-output