# why is the Jenkin's environment variable being set like this?

Tags: bash, jenkins

i have a Jenkinsfile that is exporting an environment variable like this

```
environment {
        USERNAME = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'set +x && echo $username').trim()
        PASSWORD = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'set +x && echo $password').trim()
    }
```

why not just do `echo $username` and `echo $password`? I am not well-versed with bash scripting so I am not understanding the reasoning behind the rest

Comment: The code seems to set `USERNAME` to be equal to `username`. I don't know enough about Jenkins, but perhaps it is possible to turn on tracing globally for shell scripts. The code does not want to make this trace information being present in `USERNAME` and therefore turns tracing off. However, trace information is written to stderr, so this should not be an issue here. Hence I agree with you that I don't see a point in doing the `set +x`.

Comment: Even better question is why bother with `sh` step at all? You can access environment variables through `env` map, so `USERNAME = env.username` would achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

### #1 sh(returnStdout: true, script: '...')

It is a useful feature to query or execute some bash command and get the value as string to save it into a variable

### #2 set +x

The main reason to append `set +x` to the scripts in jenkins and other similar platform is to avoid the print of script or sh. Your script is small so the log does not bother the eyes. But is the script is big, the log is so noise

**pipeline**

In this sample I used  whoami to simulate some bash command

```
pipeline{
    
    agent any
    
    environment {
        USERNAME = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'echo $(whoami)').trim()
        PASSWORD = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'echo $(whoami)').trim()
    }    
    
    stages {
        stage ('Stage 1') {
            steps {
                script {
                   println "USERNAME: $USERNAME"
                   println "PASSWORD: $PASSWORD"
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

**without set +x**

[image]

**with set +x**

`USERNAME = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'set +x && echo $(whoami)').trim()`

[image]

It is in my backlog open it a pull request to add a parameter to help with that. Currently there is no way to hide the script without set +x:  [How do I turn off command echo in Jenkins pipeline groovy scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54045677/how-do-i-turn-off-command-echo-in-jenkins-pipeline-groovy-scripts)